# Display Mat-Table without duplicate values

Tags: angular

There are three columns in my mat-table such as part, type and name.
I am getting same data from service for all these columns when I bind them it is showing duplicate data in multiple rows. Now I want to club them all and want to show only one row in table.

[image]

```
  loadPartsUsageData(reqObj) {
this.partUsageService.getdata(reqObj)
  .subscribe(
    success => {
      this.loaddataSource(success);
      this.updata = success;
      console.log('data', this.updata);
    },
    error => {
      this.updata = {};
      this.partusageDataSource = [];
      this.totalRecords = 0;
    },
    () => {
    }
  );
```

}

```
  loaddataSource(response: any) {
const dataWithIndex: any[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(response.partDetails).length; i++) {
  dataWithIndex.push({
    // id: i,
    partType: response.partDetails[i].partType === null ? '' : response.partDetails[i].partType,
    basepartNumber: response.partDetails[i].basepartNumber === null ? '' : response.partDetails[i].basepartNumber,
    partD1d: response.partDetails[i].partD1d === null ? '' : response.partDetails[i].partD1d,
    partDescription: response.partDetails[i].partDescription === null ? '' : response.partDetails[i].partDescription,
    partNumber: response.partDetails[i].partNumber === null ? '' : response.partDetails[i].partNumber
  });
}
console.log('Valid data......', response, response.partDetails);
this.partusageDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(dataWithIndex);
this.totalRecords = Object.keys(response.partDetails).length;
console.log('Total records', this.totalRecords);
console.log('partdetails List Details', response.partDetails);
this.partusageDataSource.filterPredicate = this.customECUTableFilterPredicate();
```

}
response from service
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1EU2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmAbA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component, you can create a new array and add any items from the array you are currently using to this if they aren't already added (based on matching properties ) E.g, if current array is called items:

```
this.items.forEach(i =>
 {
!this.itemsGroup.some(ig => 
ig.name == i.name && 
ig.part == i.part &&
ig.type == i.type) ? 
this.itemsGroup.push(i) : null;
 });
```

Then use the itemsGrouped array to populate your table.

Alternatively, 'for' loop is generally reported as being faster so could use it instead and move the comparison logic into a function, e.g. group(item: Item):

```
for (var i = 0, len = this.items.length; i < len; i++) {
this.group(this.items[i]);
}
```

Amended your code sample to show how it could work:

```
loaddataSource(response: any) {
const dataWithIndex: any[] = [];
const groupedData: any[] = [];

for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(response.partDetails).length; i++) {
  dataWithIndex.push({
    // id: i,
    partType: response.partDetails[i].partType === null ? '' : response.partDetails[i].partType,
    basepartNumber: response.partDetails[i].basepartNumber === null ? '' : response.partDetails[i].basepartNumber,
    partD1d: response.partDetails[i].partD1d === null ? '' : response.partDetails[i].partD1d,
    partDescription: response.partDetails[i].partDescription === null ? '' : response.partDetails[i].partDescription,
    partNumber: response.partDetails[i].partNumber === null ? '' : response.partDetails[i].partNumber
  });
}

dataWithIndex.forEach(i =>
 {
!groupedData.some(ig => 
ig.basepartNumber== i.basepartNumber && 
ig.partD1d== i.partD1d &&
ig.partNumber == i.partNumber) ? 
groupedData.push(i) : null;
 });

console.log('Valid data......', response, response.partDetails);
this.partusageDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(groupedData);
//etc
```

Comment: Hi can you please give me a stackblitz example.

Comment: Can you add code samples to your question to give an idea of how it is currently working in the background?

Comment: Hi I added my code and response which I a, getting from service.

Comment: So just create another array any[] same as dataWithIndex. Then just before your console.log('Valid data... line, add the loop but replace 'this.items' with dataWithIndex and this.itemsGroup with the new array name. No need to use 'this.' as arrays are declared in same function. Then use the new array as your MatTableDataSource

Comment: for (var i = 0, len = this.items.length; i < len; i++) {
this.group(this.items[i]);
}
is this the for loop which I need to paste over there

Comment: Well you are currently using one within a function so creating the group array in same place would work. Once it is working you could always experiment for the best option.

Comment: Hello can you please be more specific I am not able to understand as I am new to angular.
sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add code to your sample. Based on how you are looping there may be another way to do this at that point but this way will work for a 'post-intial populate' grouping

Comment: No prob, having seen your code now with the way you are adding the items to the first array, the groupng could be done at that point instead but would need a different solution. This gets it going for now anyway.